# react-awsome-query-builder not able to bind default tree value to the widget

Tags: reactjs, query-builder

I am using react-awesome-query-builder in my project.
I have stored generated tree at the backend.
When I tried to bind the same tree again to query builder in reading mode then my Field and Operator got the right places but Value is not rendered.

the same issue is reported on GitHub by someone 16 days ago.
https://github.com/ukrbublik/react-awesome-query-builder/issues/354

Any solution to this issue?